# Admob not showing real Ads only Test Ads

Tags: android, angular, admob, ads

Guys Need help, in the past admob ads were working perfectly, but after that my AdMob's dashboard showed zero everywhere even in the number of requests and my app doesn't show any ads despite I don't have an ad serving limit.
Now I update all SDKs in my app, test ads are working but real ads don't show:
here some screenshot preview:
[Admob Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne96G.png)

Here is some SDK information:

Variables Gradle:

```
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 32
targetSdkVersion = 30
androidxActivityVersion = '1.2.0'
androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.2.0'
androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.1.0'
androidxCoreVersion = '1.3.2'
androidxFragmentVersion = '1.3.0'
junitVersion = '4.13.1'
androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.2'
androidxEspressoCoreVersion = '3.3.0'
cordovaAndroidVersion = '7.0.0'
```

Google Play Service Ads:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.1.0
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting in the log cat?

Comment: ad failed to load 3

Comment: Did you add app-ads txt file?

Comment: I have just add it maybe the problem was caused by app-ads.txt